# Не удается установить PyAudio

Tags: pycharm, pip, pyaudio

При попытке установки PyAudio :

```
(venv) C:\Users\oleg_\PycharmProjects\project_v1>pip install PyAudio 
Collecting PyAudio 
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f0472.. 
a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz 
Installing collected packages: PyAudio 
Running setup.py install for PyAudio ... error 
Complete output from command C:\Users\oleg_\PycharmProjects\project_v1\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setup 
tools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\oleg_\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yuspyvjh\\PyAudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(t 
okenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" 
install —record C:\Users\oleg_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-zr6sf70g\install-record.txt —single-version-externally- 
managed —compile —install-headers C:\Users\oleg_\PycharmProjects\project_v1\venv\include\site\python3.7\PyAudio: 
running install 
running build 
running build_py 
creating build 
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 
copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 
running build_ext 
building '_portaudio' extension 
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7 
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release 
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c 
/nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -IC:\Users\oleg_\PycharmProjects\project_v1\venv\include -IC:\Users\oleg 
_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include -IC:\Users\oleg_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include "-IC: 
\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule 
.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj 
_portaudiomodule.c 
src/_portaudiomodule.c(27): fatal error C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: stdio.h: No such file or directo 
ry, 
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\b 
in\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2 

—------------------------------------— 
Command "C:\Users\oleg_\PycharmProjects\project_v1\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__ 
='C:\\Users\\oleg_\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yuspyvjh\\PyAudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(_ 
_file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install —record C:\User 
s\oleg_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-zr6sf70g\install-record.txt —single-version-externally-managed —compile —inst 
all-headers C:\Users\oleg_\PycharmProjects\project_v1\venv\include\site\python3.7\PyAudio" failed with error code 1 in 
C:\Users\oleg_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yuspyvjh\PyAudio\ 
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available. 
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install —upgrade pip' command.
```

При попытке обновить pip :

```
(venv) C:\Users\oleg_\PycharmProjects\project_v1>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\oleg_\pycharmprojects\project_v1\venv\lib\site-packages (18.1)
```

Comment: компилятор сломан похоже. Stdio.h найти не может.

Comment: src/_portaudiomodule.c 27 строчка в этом файле

Comment: @eri подскажи пожалуйста, как я могу исправить это?